# Goals in actionlib

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The actionlib accepts only one goal at a time. Does it mean I cannot do this:

```
#goal
int32[] goal
or
#goal
int32 goal1
int32 goal2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9112/goals-in-actionlib/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The goal of an action is defined by a single message type it can have compound data inside. For example the VisionPlugDetection.action has a several data types in the goal definition of the action (string, geometry_msgs/PoseStamped, bool) while the result has only one data type (geometry_msgs/PoseStamped):

```
# Goal
string camera_name
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped prior
# Origin is on left (FALSE) for left forearm looking at plug on base,
# on right (TRUE) for right forearm looking at plug in gripper.
bool origin_on_right
---
# Result
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped plug_pose
---
# Feedback
```

Actionlib can only act on one goal at a time, meaning as goals are received by the action they are buffered and acted on in the order received. Depending on the application sequences of goals will either be preempted, queued, or acted on concurrently. This behavior is dependent on the action server implementation.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3